# Tangent vector fields imply tangent Lie bracket

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves, lie-derivative

Let $f,g$ two smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$ tangent to a surface $S$ at every point.
I think it implies that the Lie bracket $[f,g]$ is tangent to $S$.

---

I start from the fact that
$$
[f,g](x) = \lim_{e\to 0} \frac{1}{e^2}\left[\exp(ef)\exp(eg) - \exp(eg)\exp(ef) \right]x
$$

Since, for $s$ small enough, the curve $s\to (\exp(sf)\exp(sg) - \exp(sg)\exp(sf))(x)$ is contained in $S$ this proves that $[f,g]$ is tangent to $S$.

am I missing something ?

Comment: I think it's OK.

Comment: Why do you think this curve is contained in $S$? Are you assuming that $S$ is affine? My proof would be quite different.

Comment: No I am not assuming $S$ affine. $S$ is a general differential subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is indeed the point I am not sure, I tried to find counter examples